# How do you describe congruence classes in general?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I have studied equivalence and congruence classes before, know the definitions, but I am still unable to work with congruences.

Could you please explain, how do the congruence classes look? For example, if I have this algebra (permutation cycle, in particular)

**$C_n$** := $(\{0, 1, . . . , n − 1\}, (0  1 . . . n − 1))$

where elements are just 0,1,2,3,4, and the operation on this set maps each element to the subsequent one and the $n-1$ element is mapped "back" to zero.

My struggle is that I see a congruence relation as some equivalence relation - i.e. set of equivalence classes. But I fail to see how these classes could look.

Can they have one element generating the others? Or more elements? And How can two elements of the underlying set belong to a congruence class, if the class has only one element for example? And how do you describe all congruences of an algebra?

I just can´t wrap my head around how to see the congruence classes and their elements in my head.

I am not sure if I describe my question well, but if it is not clear, I will try to specify my problem.

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Please specify your question. What would be the elements of $C_n$ and what specific congruence relation are you talking about?

Comment: @Berci I tried to specify. This algebra in particular is usually called permutation cycle. It is just set of elements with an algebra operation that maps x to x+1 for each x, except n-1, that is mapped to 0. And I am not talking about any specific congruence relation. This is basically what my question is about. How can you tell what congruence relations can exist on some given algebra. How do they look, what elements do their congruence classes have.
I hope I helped to make that clear.

Comment: A congruence relation is generated by a *pair* of elements or a set of pairs, and basically wants to define a new *equality* so that it's extended along the given operation(s). For example if $1\alpha 3$ for a congruence $\alpha$ of $C_6$ then it forces $2\alpha 4,\dots,0\alpha 2$. I might spell it out tomorrow in an answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque I know what is the operation and how the algebra in the example looks. It is just an example tho, my doubts are about how the congruence classes are formed (in general). I am after something similar to Berci´s comment above. The example is just illustrative. Any similar example is appreciated too.

Comment: @Berci Thank you, you understand exactly what I am asking. Yes, that is my root problem. As you said, if 1α3, I still dont see, why also 2α4 or 0α4.(Even if I know what a def. of C6 is). If I understand well, if $1 \alpha 3$ then $3 = k*n + 1$, which determines what elements are also related by $\alpha$. But I still dont see how to know if there are more such congruence relations or what are "classes" of $\alpha$. So I would appreciate longer answer or comment on that definitely. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $C_n$ here is a unary algebra, having a single (cyclic) operation $s=x\mapsto x+1$ mod $n$.

If we have an algebraic structure $A$, then a congruence relation $\theta$ on $A$ is defined as an equivalence relation (i.e. it's a subset of $A\times A$ satisfying reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity) which 'behaves like equality', i.e. also *respects* all given operations of $A$ in the sense that whenever $\mu:A^n\to A$ is an $n$-ary operation, and $a_1,\dots,a_n,\ b_1,\dots,b_n\ \in A$ such that $a_i\,\theta\, b_i$ (meaning $(a_i,b_i)\in\theta$) for each $i=1,\dots,n$, then also
$$\mu(a_1,\dots,a_n)\ \theta\ \mu(b_1,\dots,b_n)\,.$$
(In other words, $\theta$ is also a *subalgebra* of $A\times A$.)

Congruence relations can be generated by a given *pair* $(a,b)$ of elements or by a given set $S$ of pairs, i.e. any relation $S\subseteq A\times A$ determines a congruence relation, namely the intersection of all congruence relations (as subsets of $A\times A$) which contain $S$.

---

Back to $C_n$, take for example $n=6$ and let's figure out the congruence relation $\alpha$ generated by the pair $(1,3)$.

By symmetry, we can deduce $3\,\alpha \,1$.
Applying the condition on the operation $s$ of $C_6$, we get that $1\,\alpha\, 3$ implies
$$2=s(1)\ \alpha\ s(3)=4$$
that is $(2,4)\in\alpha$.
Which further implies $3\,\alpha\, 5$, then $4\,\alpha\,0,\ 5\,\alpha\,1$ and $0\,\alpha\,2$.

Using symmetry and transitivity, we see that $0,2,4$ are all in $\alpha$ relation with each other and similarly are $1,3,5$. These are the two equivalence classes now. You can verify that this partition indeed defines a congruence relation, and as each pair of it was forced, it must be the smallest congruence relation containing $(1,3)$.

Try to find the congruence generated by $(2,5)$. How many equivalence classes will that have?

Now if a congruence relation $\beta$ is given on $C_n$, let $b$ the smallest among $1,2,\dots,n-1$ such that $0\,\beta\,b$.
Then try to show that $b$ divides $n$ and $\beta$ is generated by the pair $(0,b)$ and specifically,
$$x\,\beta\,y\ \iff\ b\,|\,(y-x)\,.$$
Finally, it's possible that such a $b$ doesn't exist (when $0$ is only $\beta$-related to itself). Prove in that case $\beta$ is the equality relation (aka 'diagonal') $\{(a,a):a\in A\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I really apprecaite the time that you took writing this, really helped!

Comment: Btw, when a congruence class has only one element related to itself, it is called trivial class? (Even if it´s not zero element).